# Make [PKCS12] a synonym of [PKCS#12]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Please make make [pkcs12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs12) a synonym of [pkcs#12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%2312). Also see:

- [PKCS#12 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pkcs%2312/info)
- [PKCS12 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pkcs12/info)

I'm guessing the same should be done for all the PKCS's.

Comment: since theres 30 questions, i'd just retag them manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is done now. I saw [pkcs11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs11) / [pkcs#11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%2311) was given the same treatment, so I saw no issues.